# What set are these 3 Lego bags from? Lots of white and tan

Tags: set-identification

My nephew purchased this Lego set at a thrift store, we need your help identifying what set it is. Thanks for your help!

[image: bag 1 of 3 Lots of white and tan]

[image: bag 2 of 3 Lots of white and tan]

[image: bag 3 of 3 already built and repackaged]

Answer (score 3):

The top bag is from [41711-1 Emma's Art School](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=41711-1).

Based on

- White Hinge Plate 1 x 4 Swivel (2429 / 2430)
- Sand Green Plate 1 x 10

[image: 41711-1 Emma's Art School]

The second bag looks like it could be from the same set based on a few pieces I looked at.

The last bag, however, already has things built, so is almost definitely not sealed. It might be a mix, it might be everything from the other bags, there's no practical way I know of to be sure. The White 6 x 12 plate is in that set, at least. And the mini-doll with the hoodie looks like Felix. And the built part on the left, with the yellow circular pieces, seems to be in the picture near the bicycle.

Comment: Thanks so much! We'll look up the set instructions and see how it goes